# Semicolon in windows folder name prevents application from loading its dlls

Tags: windows, dll

My application (C++) loads its dll by linking against the stub library, the dll is then expected to reside in the same directory as the executable.

However I've had a report from a user who received the error message "System Error - The program can't start because xyz.dll is missing from your computer".
It turns out the reason is that he had my application installed in a path that contains a semicolon (which is supposed to be a valid character in ntfs file names)

I went on to try with a couple of other applications I have installed on my System and some (audacity, git, python, vlc) exhibit the same behaviour (append semicolon to folder name -> dlls can't be loaded) but most don't.

So now I'm wondering: Is this an error on my part? If so: what am I doing wrong? What would I have to do for the dll to be discovered even if its in a path with a semicolon?

Comment: Hi, Have you solved this problem? I've the same now :(